# For Loops: How to avoid loop when index is used to call multiple different column values?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, vectorization, apply

I have a large dataset of medical records (20 million rows). I want to create a new column that is populated by the value of a particular row within each group.

## What the Data Looks Like

The data looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(
        ICUSTAY_ID = c(1,1,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6),
        DATA = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0), 
        OFFSET = c(-20,0,-1500, 150, 155, 159, 300, -2000, 30, 100, 120),
        AA_FIRST = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA,NA,1,NA), 
        LABRESULT = c(4, 5, 3.5, 4.1, NA, 3.0, 5.5, 2.1, 2.5, NA, 3.5) )


          ID DATA OFFSET AA_FIRST LABRESULT
          1    0    -20       NA       4.0
          1    0      0       NA       5.0
          5    0  -1500       NA       3.5
          5    0    150       NA       4.1
          5    1    155        1        NA
          5    0    159       NA       3.0
          5    0    300       NA       5.5
          6    0  -2000       NA       2.1
          6    0     30       NA       2.5
          6    1    100        1        NA
          6    0    120       NA       3.5
```

## What I Want the Data to Look Like

For each group of IDs, I want to find the row in that group that has AA_FIRST=1 (there will only be 1 of these per ID group), find the OFFSET value for that row, and then paste this OFFSET value into a new column called refOFFSET for *all* the rows of the ID. I want the result to look like this:

```
          ID DATA OFFSET AA_FIRST LABRESULT refOFFSET
          1    0    -20       NA       4.0        NA
          1    0      0       NA       5.0        NA
          5    0  -1500       NA       3.5       155
          5    0    150       NA       4.1       155
          5    1    155        1        NA       155
          5    0    159       NA       3.0       155
          5    0    300       NA       5.5       155
          6    0  -2000       NA       2.1       100
          6    0     30       NA       2.5       100
          6    1    100        1        NA       100
          6    0    120       NA       3.5       100
```

ID group 5 has AA_FIRST=1 corresponding to an OFFSET of 155, so the refOFFSET column for all rows with ID=5 were populated by 155.

ID group 6 has AA_FIRST=1 corresponding to an OFFSET of 100, so the refOFFSET column for all rows with ID=6 were populated by 100.

There may not necessarily be an AA_FIRST=1 for an ID group. This is the case for ID group 1. ID Group 1 does not have any AA_FIRST=1, so it's refOFFSET is NA.

Not all ID values may exist. For example, ID's number 2, 3, and 4 do not exist.

## My Current Approach

My code to do this right now consists of *for* loops and *if/else* statements. I would like to come up with a vectorized or *apply* form instead. My *for* loop takes too long with 20 million rows.

```
data$refOFFSET <- NA #initialize column called refOFFSET

for (i in 1:length(data$ID)){
        if (!length(which(data$ID==(data$ID[i]) & data$AA_FIRST==1))) { #if it's integer0
                next #go on to next i
        }else{
                tmpval <- data$OFFSET[which(data$ID==(data$ID[i]) & data$AA_FIRST==1)]} 
        data$refOFFSET[i] <- tmpval #create column whose value is equal to the reference OFFSET for each ID (i.e. the OFFSET where AA_FIRST=1)
}
```

## Question

**Does anyone know how to write the above code in a vectorized or apply form? Anything that might speed up the computation?** Thank you!

Edit: My reproducible example data and displayed original data were slightly different. I corrected this.

Comment: Do you use some kind of database like SQL-Server? Because if you do, it would be much easier

Comment: Yes, I could go back and re-extract the data on an SQL server. The columns shown above already come from multiple different table mergers and both DATA and AA_FIRST come from computations done in R. I think it would be easier to try to work with the data in R to avoid re-doing these computations in SQL, but if there's no good way to do it in R, then I'd definitely be open to the SQL approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also subset for rows where `AA_FIRST == 1` and save it as a lookup table (similar to a dictionary in Python), and then match based on `ID`.

```
data<- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6),
  DATA = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0), 
  OFFSET = c(-20,0,-1500, 150, 155, 159, 300, -2000, 30, 100, 120), 
  AA_FIRST = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA), 
  LABRESULT = c(4.0, 5.0, 3.5, 4.1, NA, 3.0, 5.5, 2.1, 2.5, NA, 3.5) )

dict <- subset(data, data$AA_FIRST==1)[c("ID", "OFFSET")]

data$refOFFSET <- dict[match(data$ID, dict$ID), 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try with `dplyr`. Grouping the dataframe by `ICUSTAY_ID` we find a index which is minimum for `AA_FIRST=1` and use the corresponding `OFFSET` value for the entire group.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(ICUSTAY_ID) %>%
  mutate(refOFFSET = OFFSET[which.min(AA_FIRST == 1)])

#   ICUSTAY_ID  DATA OFFSET AA_FIRST LABRESULT refOFFSET
#    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1      1     0    -20       NA       4.0        NA
#2      1     0      0       NA       5.0        NA
#3      5     0  -1500       NA       3.5       155
#4      5     0    150       NA       4.1       155
#5      5     1    155        1        NA       155
#6      5     0    159       NA       3.0       155
#7      5     0    300       NA       5.5       155
#8      6     0  -2000       NA       2.1       100
#9      6     0     30       NA       2.5       100
#10     6     1    100        1        NA       100
#11     6     0    120       NA       3.5       100
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very clever use of the OFFSET[...]. This is exactly the type of answer I was hoping for. 
This works perfectly on the example data I provided. However, when I try it on my real data, I get an error: _"Error: incompatible size (0), expecting 7 (the group size) or 1"_
Your code runs fine if I change it to OFFSET[1] or OFFSET[AA_FIRST == 1]. There's something about adding the _which.min_ that causes this error. I'm not sure where to begin debugging it. Any ideas what might be causing the error? 
Thank you again!

Comment: @LinaColucci It would be difficult to debug the error message without the actual data. Can you share a subset of a date using `dput` which is causing error so that the error is reproducible at my end as well?

Comment: Hi Ronak: @Carmen-Lai below found the solution for this by using _match_ instead of _which.min_.  Removing the second "1" from AA_FIRST column reproduces the error: structure(list(ICUSTAY_ID = c(1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6
), DATA = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), OFFSET = c(-20, 
0, -1500, 150, 155, 159, 300, -2000, 30, 100, 120), AA_FIRST = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), LABRESULT = c(4, 5, 3.5, 
4.1, NA, 3, 5.5, 2.1, 2.5, NA, 3.5)), .Names = c("ICUSTAY_ID", 
"DATA", "OFFSET", "AA_FIRST", "LABRESULT"), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @LinaColucci I am not sure what is wrong because this `which.min` code still works for me even for the new dataset you shared.

Comment: Hmm that is very strange. Carmen was also able to reproduce this error (and find the fix) with this new dataset. Thanks again for the dplyr solution! I will definitely make use of it in other situations.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own function and use apply like this:

```
my_function<-function(input_vector){
    if(is.na(input_vector[4])){return(NA)}
    if(input_vector[4]==1){
        return(input_vector[3])
    }else{retun(NA)}
}

data<- data.frame(
        ID = c(5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6),
        DATA = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0), 
        OFFSET = c(-1500, 150, 155, 159, 300, -2000, 30, 100, 120), 
        AA_FIRST = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA,NA,1,NA), 
        LABRESULT = c(3.5, 4.1, NA, 3.0, 5.5, 2.1, 2.5, NA, 3.5) )

ref_col=apply(data,1,my_function)
data[,'refOFFSET']=ref_col

refOFFSET_val_idx=which(!is.na(ref_col))
refOFFEST_lookup_df=data[refOFFSET_val_idx,c('ID','refOFFSET')]
for(i in 1:nrow(refOFFEST_lookup_df)){
    ID_to_change_idx=which(data$ID==refOFFEST_lookup_df[i,'ID'])
    data[ID_to_change_idx,'refOFFSET']=refOFFEST_lookup_df[i,'refOFFSET']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), grouped by "ICUSTAY_ID", we get the index of the 1 value in 'AA_FIRST' to get the corresponding 'OFFSET' value and assign (`:=`) it to create the 'refOFFSET'.  This should be very efficient as we are assigning in place.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, refOFFSET := OFFSET[match(1, AA_FIRST)], by = ICUSTAY_ID]
data
#    ICUSTAY_ID DATA OFFSET AA_FIRST LABRESULT refOFFSET
# 1:          1    0    -20       NA       4.0        NA
# 2:          1    0      0       NA       5.0        NA
# 3:          5    0  -1500       NA       3.5       155
# 4:          5    0    150       NA       4.1       155
# 5:          5    1    155        1        NA       155
# 6:          5    0    159       NA       3.0       155
# 7:          5    0    300       NA       5.5       155
# 8:          6    0  -2000       NA       2.1       100
# 9:          6    0     30       NA       2.5       100
#10:          6    1    100        1        NA       100
#11:          6    0    120       NA       3.5       100
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `match` to find the index seems to solve the incompatible size error you mentioned in Ronak Shah's solution.

```
  data %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(refOFFSET = OFFSET[match(TRUE, AA_FIRST==1)])
```

> "For a logical vector x with both FALSE and TRUE values, which.min(x)
>   and which.max(x) return the index of the first FALSE or TRUE,
>   respectively, as FALSE < TRUE. However, match(FALSE, x) or match(TRUE,
>   x) are typically preferred, as they do indicate mismatches."

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/which.min.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by filtering and then remerging the data frame.

```
    foo <- data[! is.na(data$AA_FIRST),c('ID','OFFSET')]
    colnames(foo) <- c("ID", "refOFFSET")
    result <- merge(data, foo, on = "ID")
```

Comment: I needed to change the last line to `result <- merge(tmp, foo, by = "ID", all.x = T)` and then it works!